# When I friend someone on Facebook, who finds out?

Tags: facebook

There's someone with some obsessive ill-will toward me who I'm still Facebook friends with.

Given that, when I friend people, under what circumstances will this ill-willed person find out about it?  (Assuming I've set up my privacy to not reveal anything about my friending actions).  For example, if I friend someone who my nemesis is already friends with, will my nemesis see my new befriending?

And how would any of this change if I "unfriended" the nemesis?